# Timezones and JSON reading with jersey

Tags: java, javascript, json, date, jersey

On my page the user enters a birthday. The model saves the date as javascript date. In the request the date gets converted to UTC with **the timezone offset of the date given**. On the server side jersey reads that date and adds **the current timezoneoffset**.

So as of writing this post what happens (server is in CET):

User enters:

```
01/03/1967
```

Client transfers:

```
JSON.stringify(new Date(1967,2,1))
"1967-02-28T23:00:00.000Z"
```

Server adds one hour, and gets correctly `01/03/1967`.

But if the user enters

```
01/04/1967
```

Client transfers:

```
JSON.stringify(new Date(1967,3,1))
"1967-03-31T22:00:00.000Z"
```

Server adds one hour, and gets incorrectly `31/03/1967`. When DST gets involved in summer, the server would probably add two hours and the date is correct again.

I am now transferring only the date string (not as date object, so just what the user entered).

Does somebody else have this issue? How to solve this discrepancy?

I am not getting any deterministic behaviour out of JSON.stringify, why it sometimes uses 2 hours offset and why sometimes only one hour.

For example see following dates:

```
JSON.stringify(new Date(1981,5,1))
""1981-05-31T22:00:00.000Z""
JSON.stringify(new Date(1980,5,1))
""1980-05-31T23:00:00.000Z""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have choosen the wrong model for handling your input. Basically you start with a plain date (without time and without timezone). So you should keep this structure. That means converting the input to a JavaScript-Date (including time and timezone) is not really okay as this introduces the problems you observe.

Unfortunately JavaScript in its built-in version does not offer a plain date as data type. **But you can at least convert the user input into a String with ISO-8601-format, namely: yyyy-MM-dd**

Then you send this string via JSON and on server side you can parse it to what ever type you wants (here I again recommend to use a plain date as model like `java.time.LocalDate` in Java 8 or `org.joda.time.LocalDate` or similar). But even if you choose `java.util.GregorianCalendar` your timezone problems should go away because the date will not be changed but only supplemented with (unnecessary) time and timezone informations of the server.

Note: If Jersey still reqires a full date-time-zone-input produced by JSON then you can try to add a suitable time part (for example midnight) and a suitable time zone part manually to the string which serves as JSON-input.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing now, as I wrote: "I am now transferring only the date string (not as date object, so just what the user entered)." But thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Waxolunist Ah okay, have not read this sentence. Well, I think that is the BEST way so you escape all these weird time zone problems. It will not be good for you to introduce an intermedium JavaScript-object which uses time zones. No tricky workaround based on such a type can really heal the problem that this approach falsifies what the real input was (a plain date).